# Working with DatePicker with some restrictions on Date and Time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uidatepicker

I am working with DatePicker and I want to set specific restrictions on the selection of Date Picker by user,I want the

```
start day of the week - tuesday 
end day of the week   - saturday
start time - 16:00:00
end time -    19:00:00
```

So friends please share your thoughts on this.

Whether we should use NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use next properties of `UIDatePicker`:

*The minimum date that a date picker can show:*

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *minimumDate
```

*The maximum date that a date picker can show:*

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *maximumDate
```

Comment: `NSDate objects represent a single point in time.` - so `NSDate` object already contains time.

Answer (score 1):

You can set maximum and minimum limit to UIDatePicker as given,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"04-16-1983 20:30:15"];
NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10-16-1983 10:20:30"];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:startDate];
[datePicker setMaximumDate:endDate];
```

Hope this will help you.